# Search for a URL in a file and replace with local file path from commandline

Tags: sed

I have a Python file on disk, and I want to search a line in the function and replace the URL in the line with a local file path.

```
def showBuilderHelp():
    from webbrowser import open as openUrl
    openUrl('https://github.com/jobyski/public_help_v1.1.pdf')
```

when I tried with sed

```
sed -i  's/https://github.com/jobyski/public_help_v1.1.pdf/file:///on/disk/path/file/public_help_v1.1.pdf/g'  thefile.py
```

but this throws error

> sed: couldn't open file `https:/github.com/jobyski/public_help_v1.1.pdf/g` No such file or directory

I am not an expert in sed or grep.

Comment: For substitution of `/` in `sed` you need to escape it `\/` OR quote your `sed` inside `"` is what I could see at first glance of this code, not tried these yet but should work IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, that was simple enough:

```
sed -i 's/https:\/\/github.com\/jobyski/file:\/\/\/on/disk\/path\/file/g' thefile.py
```

Updates the file.